# Error "communication with agent failed" when SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set but SSH_AGENT_PID is not set

Tags: ssh-agent

I'm using Visual Studio Code v1.67 on Windows 10 v21H2 to connect to an Ubuntu Server 22.04 machine. I'm running an SSH agent (v8.1) on Windows. I've set `ForwardAgent yes` in my Windows `config` file. When I start an Ubuntu terminal, the agent appears to be running in Ubuntu and has my Windows key. I can see it via `ssh-add -l`. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set to something like `/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-auth-sock-12345678` (a link to `/tmp/ssh-XXXXABCDEF/agent.1234`), but `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not set.

If I try `ssh -Tvvv git@bitbucket.org` it does not use the key in the agent and asks for my Ubuntu key password. In the verbose SSH output are the messages:

```
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
```

I can start a new agent and add the key on my Ubuntu machine using `` eval `ssh-agent`; ssh-add ``. This sets both `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` now has a path like `/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXABCDEF/agent.1234`. Now, when I test with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` it works. I don't have to enter my password. I can do things like `git push` to a remote via ssh without entering a password.

I would prefer to use the Windows agent key forwarded by VS Code. That way I never have to enter a password. I don't see why `ssh` cannot access it. This worked before I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. Is the problem with `openssh`? It's v8.9 on Ubuntu Server 22.04. I think it's v8.4 on US 21.10. Or is the problem with VS Code? Could the problem be that VS Code is not setting `SSH_AGENT_PID` when forwarding the key? Is it necessary to set `SSH_AGENT_PID` when using the agent?

Edited: I noticed that if I set just `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` from `ssh-agent`, and leave `SSH_AGENT_PID` empty, and then add the key on my Ubuntu machine, it works (`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`, etc). So, it seems `SSH_AGENT_PID` is not necessary in some cases. The problem could be there's something wrong with the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` file created when VS Code forwards the agent.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I haven't resolved this. I suspect it's an incompatibility between SSH 8.1 on Windows and 8.9 on Linux. Apparently, OpenSSH introduced something called [SSH agent restriction](https://www.openssh.com/agent-restrict.html) in v8.9. That could be what's causing my problem, although I'd be surprised if this new system was supposed to result in a "communication with agent failed" error.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem occurred to me yesterday when I was trying to forward my key to remote server in VSCode. It turned out the default installation is too old and incompatible with the server's protocol.

Here is how I solve it:

1. Open `PowerShell` with elevated privileges
2. Uninstall the default installation using:

   ```
   Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
   ```
3. (Optional) Restart if you see something like `UninstallPending` instead of `NotPresent`
4. Check if the default OpenSSH is completely uninstalled

   ```
   Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
   ```
5. Install latest client only:

   ```
   winget install Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta --override ADDLOCAL=Client
   ```

   or follow [Install Win32 OpenSSH Using MSI](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH-Using-MSI) if you don't have `winget`
6. Check installation and verify the version >= `8.9.1.0`:

   ```
   Get-Command ssh-agent
   ```
7. (Optional) Start the `ssh-agent` service if you

   ```
   Start-Service ssh-agent
   Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
   Get-Service ssh-agent
   ```
8. (Optional) Add following lines to `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host server
     ForwardAgent yes
     AddKeysToAgent yes
   ```